# Append JsonObject(s) to an existing file containing JsonArray without over-writing the whole file

Tags: android, json

I am fetching JSON with **offset** attribute(REST Api) that enables me to get as many elements as I need. So I need to append the **new json data** to the existing data in the file.

*My aim is to implement an infinite scrolling list in my application.*

Currently I am able to **re-initialize the whole data** and **overwrite the existing file** that results in greater *memory consumption* and *time*.

Is there any way to append the new incoming JSON **without overwriting** the whole file?

> JSON already stored in the file

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Laudantium quae labore nesciunt voluptate dignissimos ut vitae.",
    "description": "Modi consequuntur rerum qui beatae. At voluptatibus cum omnis quia sit. Sunt explicabo nemo architecto eum voluptate quo.",
    "created_at": "2015-07-16 15:50:21",
    "updated_at": "2015-07-20 21:41:41",
    "category": {
      "id": "16",
      "name": "Quia animi occaecati sequi.",
      "slug": "quia-animi-occaecati-sequi",
    }
  }
]
```

> Desired result

```
[
  {
    "id": "1",
    "title": "Laudantium quae labore nesciunt voluptate dignissimos ut vitae.",
    "description": "Modi consequuntur rerum qui beatae. At voluptatibus cum omnis quia sit. Sunt explicabo nemo architecto eum voluptate quo.",
    "created_at": "2015-07-16 15:50:21",
    "updated_at": "2015-07-20 21:41:41",
    "category": {
      "id": "16",
      "name": "Quia animi occaecati sequi.",
      "slug": "quia-animi-occaecati-sequi",
    }
  },
  {
    "id": "2",
    "title": "Laudantium quae labore nesciunt voluptate dignissimos ut vitae.",
    "description": "Modi consequuntur rerum qui beatae. At voluptatibus cum omnis quia sit. Sunt explicabo nemo architecto eum voluptate quo.",
    "created_at": "2015-07-16 15:50:44",
    "updated_at": "2015-07-20 21:41:57",
    "category": {
      "id": "23",
      "name": "Quia animi occaecati sequi.",
      "slug": "quia-animi-occaecati-sequi",
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: what you can do is to save the json depending on the date it receive on the device by that way file will not be overriwritten.

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

```
JSONArray sourceArray = new JSONArray(string2);
JSONArray destinationArray = new JSONArray(string1);

for (int i = 0; i < sourceArray.length(); i++) {
    destinationArray.put(sourceArray.getJSONObject(i));
}

String s3 = destinationArray.toString(); // write it into your file
```

Comment: wouldn't this overwrite the whole file? @Amy

Comment: I just post code for merging the JsonArray. You have to write code writing data into your file.

Comment: will get back to you soon. Thanks

Comment: @Amy Question was *Is there any way to append the new incoming JSON without overwriting the whole file?* ... How this "answer" answer it? Do you have a problem with reading with understanding?

Comment: @Selvin do you have knowledge of SO? Question's title edited after my answer.

Comment: better then you ... the question was unchanged in the body [link](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/31532364/1) ... are you only reading the titles?